# Logstash output kafka with SSL -> SSL Handshake failed

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, ssl-certificate, logstash

I'm new to kafka and logstash.
I want to use logstash as producer, and want to use SSL.

Here is my logstash conf

```
input {
  http {
    port => 5044
    codec => json
  }
}

output {
  kafka {
    #bootstrap_servers => ["localhost:9093"]
    bootstrap_servers => ["kafka broker's IP:9093"]
    topic_id => "test"
    codec => "json"
    ssl_truststore_location => "/etc/logstash/conf.d/test/kafka.client.truststore.jks"
    ssl_truststore_password => "passwd"
    security_protocol => "SSL"
    #ssl_keystore_location => "/etc/logstash/conf.d/test/kafka.client.keystore.jks"
    #ssl_keystore_password => "passwd"
    #ssl_key_password => "passwd"
  }
}
```

and here is the Kafka server's properties.

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092, SSL://kafka broker's ip:9093
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafka broker's ip:9092,SSL://kafka broker's ip:9093
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL

#ssl.client.auth=required

ssl.keystore.location=/etc/logstash/conf.d/test/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=dlffpr
ssl.key.password=dlffpr
ssl.truststore.location=/etc/logstash/conf.d/test/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=dlffpr
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
```

Here is how I made the SSL key. [I referenced Azure's guide.](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/azure/hdinsight/kafka/apache-kafka-ssl-encryption-authentication#update-kafka-configuration-to-use-tls-and-restart-brokers)
I'm not sure what to write in "CN: " when making kafka.server.keystore.jks.
There is no domain name, I know only it's hostname(it's kafkamanager) and ip address.
I tried to add -ext "SAN=dns:hostname,ip:kafka broker's ip"

```
# each broker
keytool -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -alias asd -genkey -keyalg RSA -validity 365 -storepass "dlffpr" -keypass "dlffpr" -dname "**CN=kafka broker's ip**" -storetype pkcs12
keytool -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -alias asd -certreq -file cert-file -storepass "dlffpr" -keypass "dlffpr"

# manager
# CA 인증서 및 키 파일 생성
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -x509 -subj "/CN=asdasdasd" -keyout ca-key -out ca-cert -nodes

# broker
#scp root@kafka broker's ip:/etc/logstash/conf.d/test/ca-cert .
#scp root@kafka broker's ip:/etc/logstash/conf.d/test/ca-key .
# CA cert-signed
openssl x509 -req -CA ca-cert -CAkey ca-key -in cert-file -out cert-signed -days 365 -CAcreateserial -passin pass:"dlffpr"

# KEY STORE, truststore add ca-cert
keytool -keystore kafka.server.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert -storepass "dlffpr" -keypass "dlffpr" -noprompt
keytool -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert -storepass "dlffpr" -keypass "dlffpr" -noprompt
# keystore add cert signed
keytool -keystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -alias asd -import -file cert-signed -storepass "dlffpr" -keypass "dlffpr" -noprompt

# manager(client)
# client keystore
keytool -keystore kafka.client.keystore.jks -alias localhost -genkey -keyalg RSA -validity 365 -storepass "dlffpr" -keypass "dlffpr" -dname "CN=localhost" -storetype pkcs12
# client cert request
keytool -keystore kafka.client.keystore.jks -alias localhost -certreq -file client-cert-sign-request -storepass "dlffpr" -keypass "dlffpr"
# CA cert
openssl x509 -req -CA ca-cert -CAkey ca-key -in ./client-cert-sign-request -out client-cert-signed -days 365 -CAcreateserial -passin pass:dlffpr
# keystore, truststore
keytool -keystore kafka.client.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert -storepass "dlffpr" -keypass "dlffpr" -noprompt
keytool -keystore kafka.client.keystore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert -storepass "dlffpr" -keypass "dlffpr" -noprompt
# keystore
keytool -keystore kafka.client.keystore.jks -alias localhost -import -file client-cert-signed -storepass "dlffpr" -keypass "dlffpr" -noprompt
```

when I start logstash and kafka, I got the error like this.
Logstash error

```
[org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector][main] [Producer clientId=producer-1] Failed authentication with /192.168.1.6 (SSL handshake failed)
[2020-06-26T16:56:59,131][ERROR][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main] [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (/kafka broker's ip:9093) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed
[2020-06-26T16:56:59,131][WARN ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main] [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker kafka broker's ip:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

Kafka error

```
INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Failed authentication with /kafka client's ip (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

It works when I set the Kafka's server properties like and I made the key with "CN:localhost"
but the logstash and kafka is not on the same machine. Please give any advice to me. Thanks.

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092, SSL://localhost:9093
```

Answer (score 0):

Today we had the same problem, trying to start kafka using SASL_SSL and two listeners (every listener with a different IP and DNS name) we reproduce your issue. When we try to start Logstash this don't start with errors like:

```
[ERROR][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main] [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (/kafka broker's ip:9093) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed
```

We create a multi domain certificate, and then set the option:

```
ssl.keystore.location
```

In the server.propierties (kafka), after restart the service, logstash works fine!